# Enabling Spring Security without AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a Spring based web application (not Spring boot) and I'm trying to enable Spring Security.

I can enable it by extending `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` and it works fine. However I want to do it using `@EnableWebSecurity`, without extending `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer`. But this annotation alone cannot enable it. Is there a way to achieve that or does this annotation alone solution works only for Spring Boot?

Thanks.

Comment: How about [`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html)?

Comment: I configure that at any case. But without extending AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer, Spring Security Filter Chain is not registered and this configuration is not in effect at all. At least I could not find a way to do.

Answer (score 1):

In a non-Boot environment, you are probably using a dispatcher servlet initializer class, for example, extending the `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`. You can register the security filter chain like this:

```java
private static void initSecurityFilter(ServletContext servletContext) {
   FilterRegistration.Dynamic securityFilter = servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain",
                DelegatingFilterProxy.class);
   final EnumSet<DispatcherType> es = EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD);
   securityFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(es, true, "/*");
}
```

and invoke it from `onStartup`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can register it by passing my config class to constructor of AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer. What I'm trying to understand/do is, if there is a way to do this only by using @EnableWebSecurity as in Spring Boot.

Comment: I'm not an expert on Spring Boot, but I don't think you can. Boot has complete control over the dispatcher servlet initialization plus a bunch of defaults which do this. In plain Spring, you have to tell the container which filters to use and which configuration classes to apply.